# DateTime->diff() crashes

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

I have a few lines of PHP that should work, but don't:

```
$date1=new DateTime();
$date2=new DateTime();

$interval=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

or

```
$interval=$date1->diff($date2);
```

I even copied the example from the DateTime Docs:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

The output is blank, when I debug, the debugger disconnects at the diff line without any error message. Is there any known bug in PHP Version 5.2.9 or has anyone else seen this behaviour?

I am currently out of ideas on what to try except for updating the PHP version. But updating all customers is not currently something I want to do...

Every little helps... Thanks!

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me. Result: "+6015 days"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime:Diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) is PHP >= 5.3.0 only.

Not sure why your debugger bails out completely - it should be complaining about an undeclared method. Maybe you need to adjust your error reporting settings?

Comment: Thank you, that was that... Even with error_reporting(E_STRICT|E_ALL); no error shows. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty right to me.
Could you try

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$date2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');

$time1 = $date1->format('Y-m-d');
$time2 = $date2->format('Y-m-d');

$difference = abs(strtotime($time1)-strtotime($time2));

$difference/= 3600*24;

print $difference.' days';
```

Comment: Note that on 32-bit systems, timestamp-based `strtotime()` suffers from the [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), while DateTime (working with 64 bit dates internally) does not. Mixing both libraries should be done only as a last resort (i.e. if it's impossible to upgrade to PHP 5.3)